# Removing invalid characters in file names

Tags: vb.net, file, character

I have the following code to remove the invalid characters in filename.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions


Public Class Form1
    Dim fp As String

    Private Sub b1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles b1.Click
        If (FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
            fp = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
            t2.Text = fp
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub b2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles b2.Click

    Dim files() As FileInfo = New DirectoryInfo(fp).GetFiles("*.*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    For Each file As FileInfo In files
        Dim oldName = file.Name
        Dim ons As String = oldName
        t1.AppendText(ons + vbNewLine)
        Dim newName = Regex.Replace(oldName, "[^0-9a-zA-Z.]", "-")
        If oldName <> newName Then
            Dim newPath = Path.Combine(file.Directory.FullName, newName)
            file.MoveTo(newPath)
        End If
    Next

End Sub

End Class
```

This seems to have problem with `FileInfo`, which cannot be converted to string at the same time the `Regex.Replace` is also giving up some overload issue.
Both, these are beyond my comprehension.

[image: The error in more detail.]

Comment: Can you modify above lines

Comment: Take a look at [the properties of FileInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2#properties) it'll help you find the Name or Full​Name property. [Regex.Replace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2) returns the value. Just changing the string won't do anything, you'll need to do something with the new filename after (like [renaming the file](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/drives-directories-files/how-to-rename-a-file)).

Answer (score 4):

`filename` is not the name of the file but a `FileInfo` instance that has a `Name` property which you should use instead.

But apart from that `Regex.Replace` returns the string but you are not doing anything with it. So what you want to do here, rename the file?

```
For Each file As FileInfo In files
    Dim oldName = file.Name
    Dim newName = Regex.Replace(oldName, "[^\w ]", "-")
    If oldName <> newName Then
       Dim newPath = Path.Combine(file.Directory.FullName, newName)
       file.MoveTo(newPath)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I am getting this exception unhandled error `System.NotSupportedException: 'The given path's format is not supported.'` from syntax `file.FullName` in line`System.IO.File.Move(file.FullName, newPath)`. Can you help

Comment: @ambrishdhaka: look at the edit, you can use [`FileInfo.MoveTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.moveto?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_FileInfo_MoveTo_System_String_). If that doesn't work, what is the value of `newPath` here? Use the debugger

Comment: @ambrishdhaka: so obbviously your regex is wrong. But that is not part of this question, is it?

Comment: @ambrishdhaka: FileInfo is not a "format", it is a class. But you dont need it since FileInfo.MoveTo exptects the new path as string. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.moveto?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_FileInfo_MoveTo_System_String_

Comment: I think you need to see the fresh picture that I have uploaded. It definitely is not about regex.